# Is it good to write javascript code inside html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm currently using angular js routing concept and have created two html files to which my page should be routed when clicked on certain options

In my main html code I have included `ng-view`

```
<div ng-view>
</div>
```

First html file

```
<h1>This is the first file</h1>
<script>
     $(document.ready(function(){
         $('h1').click(function(){
             $(this).css("color",'red');
        )
</script>
```

Second file

```
<p>This is second file</p>
```

Everything is working fine when I include the jquery code inside the first html file.

I just want to know if it is the correct and good procedure to include any javascript code inside the html code

Comment: Why not a separate js file ?

Comment: I tried writing the js code in separate js file but it is not able to find the selectors when executed, but when I included the code in the same html code it is working perfectly.

Comment: Include the js file at end of file just before close of body tag.

Comment: I'll try doing it, Thank you @Mairaj

Comment: @Harish : As stated you are trying routing in angular, don't include jQuery in you project at all. Use angular `ng-click` directive.

Comment: I think you should use directives and put ur jquery code in it.

Comment: That sounds right. I'll try to include angular ng-click @A.J

Comment: You can't write javascript INSIDE html. You can have script tags which contain javascript, but that's not html anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is valid but not a good idea to merge the behavior and presentation in a same file as it violates the separation of concerns within the application, and separation of concerns and much more is a reason why we choose angularJs. Though it will work fine. There are many down-points to this like:

1. Adds page weight
2. Difficulty (or probably impossible) for minification
3. Cannot be migrated or be used for other pages
4. Cannot be cached (needs to be downloaded every time the page is loaded)
5. Cannot be cached (needs to be downloaded every time the page is loaded)
6. No separation of concerns (harder to maintain)

Since you are using angularJS, Points to be noted are:
 1. Client side business logic sits in services that are injected into directives\controllers.
 2. UI logic is suppose to be placed in the controllers.
 3. Use Directives for DOM manipulation.

Controllers should contain view logic, but shouldn’t actually reference the DOM (referencing the DOM should only be done through directives).

So its all up to you on to how much extend you can make your application Readable, maintainable, testable etc...

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

Add jquery library

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>



$(document).ready(function(){
         $('h1').click(function(){
             $(this).css("color",'red');
        });
        });
```

[**Demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/eyws5ck8/)